# App installation request in osx

Tags: macos, node-webkit, dmg, nwjs

I have a [nwjs](http://nwjs.io/) app that was built using [nwjs-builder](https://github.com/evshiron/nwjs-builder) to create mac application (MyApp.app) and then packed into dmg image with [node-appdmg](https://github.com/LinusU/node-appdmg).

If i don't have any version of my app in Applications folder yet, I get this dialog when I double click on the app in mounted dmg image:

[image]

And when I click 'install' i get this:
[image]

Now my question is - can I control this behaviour somehow? Disable that installation offer, or find out how does it try to install and why does it fail? Could not find any clues inside generated build or in nwjs-builder or in node-appdmg.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found. The dialogs and installation code is not a part of nwjs, but chromium (chromium.src/chrome/browser/mac/install_from_dmg.mm).

I found 2 ways to disable installation request.

1. Make dmg writable - add `format: "UDRW"` to appdmg settings.
2. nwjs accepts chromium arguments by 'chrome-args' key in manifest. Specify `--no-first-run` to disable installation request. But this is a risky way, no first run key might affect many internal processes.